# Display icon depending upon managed object fragment

Tags: cumulocity

We update a status fragment in our managed objects to reflect the current operating state of the device.

I'd like to display an icon on a cockpit dashboard that changes colour as the managed object state changes.

I considered using the Cumulocity SCADA widget, is that the best way? Can I create my own widget and use it in the standard dashboard?

Perhaps a new widget type where you can choose an icon based on an object property could be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with Cumulocity, the SCADA widget is the recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

In [Scada-LTS](https://github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS/tree/develop-sdtabilit) (open source)

1. Add datasource which reads data from device for example using Modbus TCP/IP.
2. Add data point in datasource showing device status.
3. Create view with "Multistate graphics" component displaying info on device status from our data point.

You can customize "Multistate graphics" component by uploading pictures of your choice.

Please contact me if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about making an icon on the proprietary Cumulocity website using their built in UI components. I don't think this is what I'm looking for to answer the specific question above.
But it could be useful for other parts of the solution we're building so I'll take a look.